# Books and resources on PDEs that use Mathematica and Matlab

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, soft-question, numerical-methods

Can you recommend some reference books that use software like **MATLAB** and **Mathematica** to deal with the basic topics in

- *analysis of PDE* (the ones you can find in **Strauss**' book *Partial Differential Equations: An Introduction*)

and

- *numerical analysis of PDE*?

Comment: Try searching for numerical analysis with MATLAB, there's quite a number of sources available. MATLAB famously has an [extensive documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/discovery/numerical-analysis.html) on the topic. (I don't know what kind of PDEs are in Strauss' books, so it's hard to tell exactly.)

Comment: [You can check this book by P. Stavroulakis and Stepan A. Tersian](http://ee.sharif.edu/~em/Partial%20Differential%20Equations%20-%20An%20Introduction%20With%20Mathematica%20and%20Maple.pdf)